# How did the tomato become the iconic pin cushion design?

Tags: united-states, clothing, folklore

When I was growing up, my mother had a pin cushion shaped and colored like a tomato. I recently discovered that my wife's grandmother has one too, which led me to discover that tomato pin cushions are in fact quite commonplace in the U.S. (for example, [an article](https://www.marthastewart.com/1082584/mystery-tomato-pincushion) at marthastewart.com says that "pincushions come in all shapes and sizes, but the tomato is the design that prevails as the classic.")

I tried googling "why do pin cushions look like tomatoes"? I found a couple of blog posts saying it comes from a tradition of placing a tomato on the mantle to ward off bad spirits. When tomatoes were out of season, people would use balls of red cloth filled with sawdust instead, and those eventually become used as pin cushions. However these blog posts did not cite any sources.

Then I found [this blog post](https://www.worthpoint.com/articles/collectibles/the-perplexing-origin-of-the-tomato-pincushion) where someone tried researching the question. The author said she couldn't find any sources for aforementioned story of mantle piece tomatoes. All she could determine was that pin cushions were originally decorative pieces for showing off a pin collection. Since they were decorative, they came in all sorts of designs, including fruits (and tomatoes). But the author was unable to find out why the tomato design came to be the dominant pin cushion of today.

So my question is, how did the tomato become the dominant design for pin cushions?

Comment: Are tomatoes the 'iconic pin cushion design'? A quick check on Amazon for 'pin cushion' of the first 100 results just 3 are tomatoes (i.e. 3%). Admittedly, this isn't a very scientific result but it does mean that your assertion needs some evidence to back it up.

Comment: I had a quick look on Amazon and I'd say hedgehogs were the most 'popular' design (or at least the one Amazon were pushing) based on the first few search pages.

Comment: This is honestly the first time I've heard of this, but a google image search of pin cushions does return mostly tomato designs as most of the top results. So it might not be fashionable anymore in the current retail world, but I guess tomato pin cushions might have been a traditionally dominant design.

Comment: Are you in the USA? Here in the UK I'm not aware of tomato-shaped pincushions being 'a thing' - I'm more familiar with the kind with a circle of tiny 'Chinese' figures round it, or the [Cathedral window](https://suestrifles.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/cathedral-window-patchwork-pincushion/) style like my own.

Comment: My uninformed guess would be that red makes them easy to find, and if you are going with red a tomato is easier than strawberry to make.

Comment: @KillingTime There is an article (https://www.marthastewart.com/1082584/mystery-tomato-pincushion) on marthastewart.com that says, "Pincushions come in all shapes and sizes, but the tomato is the design that prevails as the classic."

Comment: @KateBunting yes I am in the USA

Comment: I'm US based, and every one I've ever seen in use was basically just a beanbag. That was mostly a long time ago though (few sew anymore), and I do see a lot that look like tomatoes when I google "pincushion".

Comment: @THummus: I'm shocked, **shocked I say**, to discover that fashion icon Martha Stewart is pushing a particular fashion of  pincushion that her company just happens to make."

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Ok fine, here are several other examples of people treating the tomato pin cushion design as iconic: https://www.simplesimonandco.com/2019/06/tomato-pin-cushion-history.html/, https://www.banaschs.com/why-do-pincushions-look-like-a-tomato/, https://www.threadsmagazine.com/2012/02/28/why-are-pincushions-frequently-made-to-resemble-tomatoes, https://journaltimes.com/local/columns/glad-you-asked-why-are-pincushions-shaped-like-tomatoes/article_cfc7c6d1-184c-53f4-8673-396c6996ef8c.html, http://www.blogforbettersewing.com/2009/12/is-your-pin-cushion-shaped-like-tomato.html?m=1

Comment: I'm probably overstating the fact that it is THE iconic design, but I'm clearly not alone in thinking that it is iconic

Comment: @THummus: [It's a very, very, old joke, even older than me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjbPi00k_ME). Check the Casablanca clip. It just seemed ironic that you would quote Martha Stewart.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens gotcha. I'm a little culturally out of the loop :)